# SQL Date Difference in Days Result Wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I want to calculate day difference between two dates.

When i calcualte Differane between '2017-01-01' and '2018-01-15' its 379 Days.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,'2017-01-01','2018-01-15')
```

But when i split dates into two sections with addition .then i Got result 378.

```
select DATEDIFF( DD,'2017-01-01', '2017-12-31') + DATEDIFF( DD,'2018-01-01', '2018-01-15')
```

anyone explain me why this happen ?

Comment: There's another day between 2017-12-31 and 2018-01-01...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple Math:

```
I:  <a,b>
II: <a,c>,<c+1,b>   where c is between a and b

I      II
b-a != b-(c+1) + c-a
b-a != b-c-1 + c-a
b-a != b-a-1       -- here is 1 missing day
```

To make it right you could use:

```
select DATEDIFF( DD,'2017-01-01', '2018-01-01') 
     + DATEDIFF( DD,'2018-01-01', '2018-01-15')
```

Answer (score 4):

`Datediff` counts the boundaries of the datetype between the two dates.

The boundary "end of '2017-12-31'-start of '2018-01-01'" is included in the first case, but not the second.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to split into two sections is to repeat the date:

```
select (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31') +
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-12-31', '2018-01-15') 
       )
```

Your version skips a day, so it is not at all surprising that it is off by a day.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the extra day that is not computed in the second case. To explain why it happens in your first query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,'2017-01-01','2018-01-15')
```

you are doing something similar to: 1 - 380 = 379.

While in the second

it's (1-365) + (1-15) = 364 + 14 = 378.

Depending on what you are after

it might be a better idea to break it down as:

```
select DATEDIFF( DD,'2017-01-01', '2018-01-01') + DATEDIFF( DD,'2018-01-01', '2018-01-15')
```